# RMTP Streamig to Twitch

Tags: ffmpeg, nginx, streaming, rtmp

First of all, i posted this question on http://unix.stackexchange.com but so far no responds. I'm reposting it here since i tried it on ubuntu 15. and got same results. I would like opinion on that.

Im streaming using OBS on Windows (QuickSync), pushing 20k bitrate to 2nd PC based on linux (Debian Jessie 8.4.0, 64bit) in local network area (1gbps lan link).

Debian Jessie is a minimal linux instalation without X server (just CLI), where i compiled and installed nginx 1.10. with rtmp module.

Debian Jessie specs:

- AMD Athlon X2 64 4200
- 2GB RAM
- Regular 7200 RPM hdd

nginx.conf:

```
root@streamer:~# cat /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
worker_processes 2;

error_log logs/error.log debug; events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

rtmp {
  server {
  listen 1935;
  chunk_size 4000;

  application transcode {
  live on;
  record off;
  exec avconv -re -i rtmp://localhost:1935/transcode/1234 -c:v libx264  -preset superfast -g 60 -keyint_min 30 -b:v 2800k -minrate 2800k -maxrate 2800k  -s 1280x720 -r 30 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/1234;
  }

  application live {
  live on;
  record off;
  push rtmp://live-ams.twitch.tv/app/STREAMKEY;
  }
}
}
```

My question is, i can stream video using SUPERFAST preset without stutters. If ill go to VERYFAST, video on twitch is stopping every like 5 seconds for a while (not buffering)

Is that athlon not enough to stream video with veryfast - faster preset? This machine got literally only needed stuff on the CLI Debian just to stream, so I'm not losing any resources.

I was quite sure i can push the quality as faster/veryfast with this rig.

After using ffmpeg 3.0.22 backports on Jessie i can say there is a slight performance boost and the quality of stream seems to be better, but still the veryfast preset is killing dual core cpu with 200% usage.

Could anyone elaborate on the topic?

Comment: If you carry on mentioning Debian this post will be closed as off-topic (cross-posting is bad enough :)  - you will have to show you used Ubuntu for trying this and it didn't work. Also, what sort of setup are you trying to acheive (e.g. `Windowz > Linux > Twitch`, `Windowz > Twitch > Linux`, etc, and how are the computers connected (the same switch, or home router, etc)

Comment: Well as You could see, im active Ubuntu supporter (doesn't matter if im using this system or no), its Windows -> Linux -> Twitch

Comment: Supporting Ubuntu is not always enough to disuade close voters... Whats the CPU (and any GPU) usage whilst under each preset?

Comment: On SuperFast im getting 100-120% of usage, AMD Athlon X2 64 4200+ (2.2 ghz per core)

Comment: WIth VeryFast im getting 180% usage, but it spikes each ~ 8 seconds (more or less) and then Video stops on twitch (understnadable why it stops on twitch, cpu goes over 200%)

Comment: You keep mentioning `ffmpeg` but your command is using `avconv`. They are different enough not to be considered the same thing.

Comment: as i was posting this i was using avconv, later on i switched to ffmpeg to compare it, which i did at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing quite a lot of research, it seems that Athlon X2 64 4200+ is not capable of pushing 720p video at 30 frame rate at veryfast/faster preset.

I need something stronger to maintain the transmission, so the CPU need to have more power.